# Fortify client downloadFPR command is not refreshed with suppressed/not issue issues

Tags: fortify

Using fortifyclient (Fortify version 4.10), I am seeing an issue where the downloaded project still contains the same thing that has been uploaded rather than refreshing with suppressed issues (done via SSC UI). Is there any option to be set while downloading to refresh the above? On the SSC, it is showing the right number (reduced after suppressed some issues) but not with downloaded fpr.

Command looks like the below ..

fortifyclient -url  -authtoken  downloadFPR -file

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a usability design flaw in Fortify SSC.

IF your users contribute "Not an Issue" type metadata ("audit data") ***by uploading an FPR***, then SSC processes the FPR and reflects the audit data as soon as processing is complete.

IF, on the other hand, users contribute any audit data via ***the SSC collaborative audit web interface***, then unfortunately the audit data entries are held in a queue until the next nightly processing (by default, at midnight).

To process right away, go to the projectversion's Details pane, and click the "Refresh" button.

Note: the "Refresh" button only appears when this sort of queued up audit data is there.  The same symptom can also happen if there is a performance problem on your server and the nightly processing is unable to complete.

Comment: Thanks Douglas. For now, I don't see the "Refresh" button on project version's details page. I will watch for this button and do.